# Strange behaviour of Leaflet fitBounds (when using L.MarkerClusterGroup)

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a mapItems layer (MarkerClusterGroup) which I use for all my map items. On the run I am adding and removing points from that layer (oh and that's GeoJSON).

And using this to fit all points nicely inside the map:

```
map.fitBounds(mapItems.getBounds());
```

Now weird thing happens when I add more points, so the bounds of the layer expands. But when I remove those points, bounds of that map (after using fitBounds of course) stays the same as maximum even though there are no points in some areas.

What could be a problem? Do I have to reset bounds of that layer somehow? Or is it better to destroy layer and create a new one each time I'm loading points to that map?

P.S. I just noticed that If I'm not using L.MarkerClusterGroup but L.FeatureGroup instead, everything works just fine... So it's something to do with clustering.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so my problem was using this to clear the layer:

```
        layer.eachLayer(
            function (sublayer) {
                layer.removeLayer(sublayer);
            }
        );
```

And this doesn't seem to work with L.MarkerClusterGroup. Instead I'm now using this and everything works fine:

```
        layer.clearLayers();
```